# Is the complexity N or N^2?

Tags: c#, algorithm, sorting, time-complexity

I was solving a question in which I've to create a unique array from the sorted array which can have duplicate elements.

I solved the solution using the following code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < sorted.Length - 1; i++)
{
    if (sorted[i] == sorted[i + 1])
    {
        unqiueList.Add(sorted[i]);
        int j = i + 1;
        while (j < sorted.Length)
        {
            if (sorted[i] != sorted[j])
            {
                break;
            }
            j++;
            i++;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        unqiueList.Add(sorted[i]);
    }
}
```

Now, I want to know the complexity of this solution.

Some people say, it is N but some say it is N^2. It hints to my mind why not ask the same question to stack overflow to have better understanding of it.

Comment: "Unique array from a sorted array" sounds like you were supposed to use Random() for a randomized output. Or is this you still doing the sorting? Unless you had that as a task, you can generally use Array and Lists sort functions for that.

Comment: @Christopher - For the unique array, I meant the array having unique elements and there is no duplicate element in it.

Answer (score 4):

Worst case is `O(N)`.

It's a bit of a nasty one, but given the fact that `i` and `j` are incremented on every iteration in the `while` loop, there is basically no looping in looping.

The algorithm doesn't allow more iterations than `sorted.Length`.

---

Interestingly; this indicates that the while loop could be replaced with an `if` statement (might not be a simple one), but it would be a nice exercise.